# ModuleNotFoundError even though the module is recognized

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

My folder structure is:

```
|-fastapi
   |-app
     |-calc.py
   |-tests
     |-mytest.py
```

In `mytest.py` I'm trying to import `calc.py`, like this:

```
from app import calc
```

In `mytest.py`, app and calc are both highlighted green, and when I hover over them, it says (module). It seems to be recognized, but when I run it, I get the error. I know this has been asked before but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: What IDE are you using, and how exactly are you running the code?

Comment: I'm using VS code. I'm just running mytest.py in the terminal

Comment: Are you running it from `tests` or from `fastapi`?

Comment: I'm running it from within the fastapi dir. Then I run the command "py -3 tests/mytest.py". I've tried other things too. I tried moving the tests dir into the app dir, with "from .. import calc" but then that gives me the error: "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer yet? @Alisha

Comment: @KazimRaza Not yet

Answer (score 0):

I create the exact same file hierarchy in my machine and then made a random function called `hello()` in the `calc.py` file, this is the code which successfully calls the function in app folder,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from app import calc
print(calc.hello())
```

maybe I misunderstood the question so here's a much detailed answer with respect to behaviour of the IDE when importing a module,

as we can see in the image below, we can import a wrong module in almost any python IDE and it won't give an error until or unless it is a smart IDE with preinstalled extensions to check as it does for other scripting languages or it won't give an error just yet, below it can be seen,

[image]

we can see that IDE doesn't show any error just yet doesn't even give a warning of any sort, but when you run the code you get this error, this is the same error which OP gets when they run their code,

[image]

this can be tried for `from app import calc` and it will give you same error as it gives for `from imagination import dreams`.

but when you add couple lines of code which are,

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

it starts to import in a similar way which OP was trying to do but only with the additional lines of code, why?
This is because they have their files in parallel to each other, which can be seen in the folders which they mention,

```
|-fastapi
   |-app
     |-calc.py
   |-tests
     |-mytest.py
```

perhaps this answers the concern which a comment mentions, I took the liberty to assume a few things but more or less this is what's happening, please rectify this answer.

Comment: the question was why is it happening, and the answer is that it is happening because it wasn't coded correctly, the right way to go about the code was to have the same parent directory in system and then call the imports from there. I hope that helps!

Comment: oh and also, I'm using spyder IDE, when you just use ```from app import calc``` it shows that it has imported the module and it hasn't been used yet, making it look like it has been imported correctly but in fact when you call the method from the imported file it gives a similar error, so the only way to go about it is to change the code, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need `__init__.py` in each folder to mark it as a package. It can be an empty file. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports) for more information.

Comment: I do have __init__.py in every folder

Comment: oh, with the dunders too? maybe try `from .app import calc` I have usually only had to do that while importing functions from files in the same folder, but Python imports are weird

Comment: Yes with the underscores. "from .app import calc" gives me the error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: maybe try `from fastapi.app import calc`?

Comment: "from fastapi.app import calc" gives me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastapi'"

Answer (score -1):

You should check and ensure you do not have an already existing file named 'calc.py'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).